# LogLogPlot seems to get stuck

Tags: plotting

The following works:

```
Plot[InverseSurvivalFunction[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], y], {y, 
  0.01, 1}]
```

But this one seems to use up 100% of CPU and takes forever

```
LogLogPlot[
 InverseSurvivalFunction[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], y], {y, 0.01,
   1}]
```

Is there a trick to get the last one to render? Tried running with `PlotPoints -> 2`, still gets stuck

Comment: MMA version 13.3 It runs just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Since it works with [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), just use those points in [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) with `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}`

```
plt = Plot[
   InverseSurvivalFunction[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], y], 
   {y, 0.01, 1}]
```

[image]

```
pts = Cases[plt, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];

ListLinePlot[pts,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]